# Doctrine Paginator fills up memory

Tags: php, symfony, memory-management, doctrine-orm, pagination

I'm having a Symfony Command that uses the Doctrine Paginator on PHP 7.0.22. The command must process data from a large table, so I do it in chunks of 100 items. The issue is that after a few hundred loops it gets to fill 256M RAM. As measures against OOM (out-of-memory) I use:

- `$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);` - disables the sql logger, that fills memory with logged queries for scripts running many sql commands
- `$em->clear();` - detaches all objects from Doctrine at the end of every loop

I've put some dumps with `memory_get_usage()` to check what's going on and it seems that the collector doesn't clean as much as the command adds at every `$paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();` call.

I've even tried to manually collect the garbage every loop with `gc_collect_cycles()`, but still no difference, the command starts using 18M and increases with ~2M every few hundred items. Also tried to manually unset the results and the query builder... nothing. I removed all the data processing and kept only the select query and the paginator and got the same behaviour.

Anyone has any idea where I should look next?

**Note:** 256M should be more than enough for this kind of operations, so please don't recommend solutions that suggest increasing allowed memory.

The striped down `execute()` method looks something like this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    // Remove SQL logger to avoid out of memory errors
    $em = $this->getEntityManager(); // method defined in base class
    $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);


    $firstResult = 0;


    // Get latest ID
    $maxId = $this->getMaxIdInTable('AppBundle:MyEntity'); // method defined in base class
    $this->getLogger()->info('Working for max media id: ' . $maxId);

    do {

        // Get data
        $dbItemsQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('m')
            ->from('AppBundle:MyEntity', 'm')

            ->where('m.id <= :maxId')
            ->setParameter('maxId', $maxId)

            ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
            ->setMaxResults(self::PAGE_SIZE)
        ;

        $paginator = new Paginator($dbItemsQuery);

        $dbItems = $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();

        $totalCount = count($paginator);
        $currentPageCount = count($dbItems);

        // Clear Doctrine objects from memory
        $em->clear();


        // Update first result
        $firstResult += $currentPageCount;
        $output->writeln($firstResult);
    } 
    while ($currentPageCount == self::PAGE_SIZE);


    // Finish message
    $output->writeln("\n\n<info>Done running <comment>" . $this->getName() . "</comment></info>\n");
}
```

Comment: Yeah same issue here, comes down to the ->setFirstResult(...) function which causes memory to build up. Still looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak was generated by Doctrine Paginator. I replaced it with native query using [Doctrine prepared statements](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) and fixed it.

Other things that you should take into consideration:

- If you are replacing the Doctrine Paginator, you should rebuild the pagination functionality, by adding a limit to your query.
- Run your command with `--no-debug` flag or `-env=prod` or maybe both. The thing is that the commands are running by default in the `dev` environment. This enables some data collectors that are not used in the `prod` environment. See more on this topic in the [Symfony documentation - How to Use the Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html)

**Edit:** In my *particular case* I was also using the bundle `eightpoints/guzzle-bundle` that implements the HTTP Guzzle library (had some API calls in my command). This bundle was also leaking, apparently through some middleware. To fix this, I had to instantiate the Guzzle client independently, without the EightPoints bundle.